# Turing machine for square root of n - transition table

Tags: turing-machines, automata

How would someone create a Turing machine that computes ceil(sqrt(n))?

n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ...
=> f(n) = 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 ....

And that I want the input tape to have n 1's in it to represent the number
i.e. 5 would be #11111
How would the turning machine with transition table for this be created?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots

Comment: @D.W.: all these methods can of course in principle be implemented on a Turing machine. But not in practice.

Answer (score 3):

Try all squares increasingly until you exceed the input. For this, consider a process that erases the first digit, then the next three, the next five, the next seven and so on, while lengthening a sequence of ones. When the input is exhausted, you are done.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Then How can I construct transition table?? Does it need infinitely many states??

Comment: @wts: that would not be a Turing machine !